# Filter and show AVAsset without completely processing

Tags: ios, swift, video, avfoundation

I would like to use only the native API (UIKit, AVFoundation, Core Image, etc.) to filter an AVAsset while showing it in an AVPlayerLayer or an equivalent UI component. I will not use GPUImage because it was extremely problematic for me.

In other words, can I filter each frame right before showing it (or a couple frames in advance) so that I do not have to completely process the entire movie every time I want to filter?

I would also accept an answer that describes how to set up a custom AVPlayerLayer with a frame buffer or something like that.

---

Also, is there a filter tag for this? All the ones I saw are for signals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AVPlayerItem` has a property `videoComposition`

You can use this property to process each frame

First way

If You want to use `CoreImage` strating from iOS9 you can use `init(asset:applyingCIFiltersWithHandler:)` method.

> To process video frames using Core Image filters—whether for display
>   or export—create a composition with this method. AVFoundation calls
>   your applier block once for each frame to be displayed (or processed
>   for export) from the asset’s first enabled video track. In that block,
>   you access the video frame and return a filtered result using the
>   provided

See [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avvideocomposition/1389556-init) for more info.

Second way

`AVVideoComposition` has a property `customVideoCompositorClass`.
You need to set that property to an instance of `AVVideoCompositing` protocol. 
[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AVCustomEdit/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013411-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) is an example. (Its in Objective-C but I think that it wouldn't be hard to translate it to swift)